# What does Kano mean by "having intercourse with Lukuss" in the ending of Texhnolyze?

Tags: japanese-language, texhnolyze

At the end of [Texhnolyze](https://youtu.be/CE-iNZXzl2s?t=186), Kano gives the following dialogue:

> I became free of all genes by having intercourse with Lukuss.

What does the above mean? How can he have intercourse with a city?

Did he mean in the sense that he lost his genes by screwing over the whole city? Still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Note the translation "by having intercourse" is from the word [交わる](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%98%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8B) (*majiwaru*) which has multiple meanings. Since I don't know Texhnolyze, I'm not sure the context and which meaning is more appropriate.

Comment: I don't think it is a mistranslation.. I felt the usbtitles were coherent most of the time @AkiTanaka

Comment: I've come to ask the same question and this question was suggested by the algorithm as similar. Maybe this f-kin monster implied that he r*ped Ran? If so, please don't verify me.